# Add language to NLTK WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I know that there is WordNet for russian language, but it's not in the list of supported languages in NLTK WordNet.
How can I add some new WordNet to NLTK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLTK has [an issue tracker](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues) and a [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nltk-dev). Feel free to post your suggestion there!

Comment: @Dimitrius, was this answer helpful?